# Touchscreen display for Google Coral Dev Board

Tags: google-coral

Have you ever tried to connect a touchscreen display to the board? Is there a model that would be compatible?
  What solutions are there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per a response from Coral team, they have only tested the Tianma TL060FVMS07-00 model, it is a touchscreen display.

Here is the full patch they made to support the Tianma display: https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/d0a15d32e9a56f67954eb6b9d19b895901787319

Comment: is this display https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10.1inch_HDMI_LCD support Google coral dev board ?

Comment: @BhanuchanderUdhayakumar Not sure about this. Cannot comment without testing it.

Comment: this is the exact device , I am trying to integrate : https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10.1inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)_(with_case) 
resolution : 1280x800